# Angular guard not working in children path

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router-guards

I am setting a guard in creditscore childpages but it seems that it is not working. I am trying to redirect back to `/creditscore` page if user is not authenticated, But when i access `/crediscore/verification` page it is not redirecting back to `/creditscore` page even if guard is enabled.
I have tried this code below.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '**',
    component: CreditScoreComponent,
    resolve: { config: WPConfigResolver },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'verification',
        component: CreditScoreSelectorComponent,
        canActivate: [ResultsGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'results',
        component: CreditScoreResultsComponent,
        canActivate: [ResultsGuard],
      }
    ]
  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

This is my results.guard.ts

```
canActivate(): boolean  {
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticatedUser()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/creditscore']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Is this the correct way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'redirecting to _the_ page'? Which page? Maybe mention the path you are trying to navigate to and the path you are ultimately ending up on.

Comment: I've updated the question. What i want is redirect back to creditscore landing page if user is not authenticated.

Comment: Have you checked what value is returned by `this.authService.isAuthenticatedUser()`? `You can put console.log(this.authService.isAuthenticatedUser())` before the if statement in guard. There might be a possibility that this method returning `true` every time.

Comment: it is returning as expected. if authenticated it returns `true` else `false`. I just don't get it why is the guard is not working. Maybe it has something to do with the `path: '**'`?

Comment: can you provide stacklitz?